# Programmatically using relativeLayout does not work with deep inner child

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to use a RelativeLayout programmatically (for some reasons regarding to dynamic creation I cannot use xml-layouts). But there is a problem, I seem to be only able to adjust children in relation to other "direct" children. See the following example:

```
public class PView extends RelativeLayout {
...

private void init(Context context) {
    int viewId = 1;

    LinearLayout center = new LinearLayout(context);
    center.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    topParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    frontRow = new LinearLayout(context);
    frontRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    TextView tmp1 = new TextView(context);
    tmp1.setText("TEST TEXT1");
    tmp1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    frontRow.addView(tmp1);


    center.setId(viewId++);
    frontRow.setId(viewId++);

    center.addView(frontRow,topParams);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    addView(center,params);

    LayoutParams bLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, frontRow.getId()); 

    bImageView = new ImageView(context);
bImageView.setImageBitmap(someBitmap);
    addView(bImageView,bLayoutParams);
}
```

This does not work, the ImageView bImageView is not positioned on the right side of frontRow. But if I use

```
        bLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, center.getId());
```

it is displayed on the right (but obviously not related to the right component).

What exactly is happening?
I did not really find much info about programmatically creating RelativeLayout's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RelativeLayout`'s rules only apply to siblings that are direct children of the `RelativeLayout` itself. What you are observing is working as designed/intended.

Comment: Hm, that is very unfortunate, and is there any point in the documentation were I could have found that myself? ... So I have to wrap the inner layout in another relativelayout to get the desired functionality?